# Check that $\sqrt{7}(\sqrt[3]{5} - \sqrt[5]{3})$ is not rational

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irrational-numbers

How to prove that $\sqrt{7}(\sqrt[3]{5} - \sqrt[5]{3})$ is not rational.

I will appreciate any proof, but I had such exercise during lecture in field theory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\alpha = \sqrt{7}(\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[5]{3})$ is rational. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[5]{3})$. This extension is then degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. However, it is also a subextension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\sqrt[5]{3})$ which has degree $15$ over $\mathbb{Q}$*, contradicting the tower law.

*Can you prove this?

Comment: Yeah, I can prove *, but I am surprised, how easy that was...

Comment: @michael That's one of the joys of working with field extensions, problems which seem somehow "obvious but hard to prove" (like the above) become a lot simpler to solve!

Comment: It's never simple with abstract algebra :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $b=\sqrt[3]5-\sqrt[3]3$. Using a computer program, you can obtain:

$$b^2=\sqrt[3]{25}-2\sqrt[3]{15}+\sqrt[3]9$$
$$b^8=-563\sqrt[3]{25}+778\sqrt[3]{15}-131\sqrt[3]9$$
$$b^{14}=276901\sqrt[3]{25}-271574\sqrt[3]{15}-67259\sqrt[3]9$$

Inverting the matrix you can find that
$$87903696b^2+406092b^8+516b^{14}=2154816\sqrt[3]{25}$$

This proves that $b^2$ is irrational and so is $7b^2$ and hence, $\sqrt 7b$.

Comment: I am not supposed to use computer program :)

Comment: Are all root index in this answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\sqrt{7}(\sqrt[3]{5} - \sqrt[5]{3})$ is rational, then so is $\sqrt{7}(\sqrt[3]{5} + \sqrt[5]{3})$.

Comment: Ok, you then suggest that I consider $\sqrt{7}\sqrt[3]{5}$, but first, how should I know that the hint is correct. I suppose it is but how can I prove that.
Unfortunately even with your hint i cannot go further :(